# Cannot I upgrade 18.10 to 19.10 without a total uninstall + a new install?

Tags: updates

I am using 18.10 now, I know it is EOL but I have not been using ubuntu for a while, and I just started using it again. But, when I do try to upgrade via GUI or console, either way, I get error of:

> “An upgrade from ‘cosmic’ to ‘eoan’ is not supported with this tool”

I know there are other similar questions here, but I could not get a neat answer from them. My question is simply,

Do I have to re-install whole operating system? If not, how can I get an update?

Comment: If 18.10 is otherwise working fine, why upgrade it? Might it be better to wait until 20.04 - the next LTS release in April 2020.

Comment: @Graham I cannot say I have problems with 18.10, though I am not a professional user to notice little changes btw, if I wait for 20.04, will it let me upgrade easily?

Comment: You will not be able to upgrade to 20.04 without an install.  If you have important data, backup or copy to another partition/hard drive.  20.04 will be supported for at least 5 years, maybe 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu only supports upgrades from one release to the next, and also from one LTS (Long Term Support) to the next LTS. In addition, upgrades are only supported between releases that are still supported. So an 18.10 should have been updated to a 19.04 while it was still supported. Because your release is EOL, there will and cannot be an easy upgrade.

Yet, "easy" is relative. In many cases, a fresh install is by far the easiest way, and is generally recommended over an upgrade.

- A fresh installation goes fast nowadays: in less than 20 minutes, you have a brand new operating system. There are several advantages to a fresh install:
- It involves a thorough cleanup of your system. Programs you forgot were there, will be removed
- Your system is freshly configures according to the most recent insights of the Ubuntu developpers. In contrast, upgrades may perpetuate old configurations instead of implementing newer, better approaches.
- Accordingly, you are less likely to bump into issues that may be related to old configuration laying around.

Comment: thanks! So, if I now install 19.10 then I will be able to upgrade to 20.04 when it is released, right?

Comment: Yes, but do so before 19.10 goes EOL.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1. Download the installer for disco: archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/disco.tar.gz

2. Extract the tar, tar -xvf disco.tar.gz
3. Change to the directory where it was extracted to. Run sudo ./disco
4. Follow the usual installer.

Comment: I wonder why this isn't provided as an option (with an "unsupported" warning, perhaps) for do-release-upgrade. I kept reading "there is no easy upgrade-path from EOL-releases to EOL-releases, but this works just fine, thanks for pointing it out.